# Have I created a loop in a nested If statement?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I wrote this code to check for an existing file and save a PDF of the report if there was not an existing file or if I choose to write over that file. I don't think I wrote the nested if correctly and I think that I may have created a loop. The code crashes on the DoCmd.Close line, however, I can't figure out what needs to change. The report I am opening should be a report of one record from my database. Something about the DoCmd.Close line seems to be causing the report to try and open all of the records. Using GoTo is probably not correct either.

Thank you for taking a look.

```
strFileName = Me.[QuoteNumber]
If Len(Dir("C:\Users\A\Desktop\Safe\Development\Qutoes\Test Quotes\" & strFileName & ".pdf")) > 0 Then
    Response = MsgBox("That file already exists! Should I continue?", vbYesNo, "File Exists!")
    If Response = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        GoTo Continue1
    End If

Else
Continue1:
    strWhere = "[ID] = " & Me.[ID]
    Debug.Print "Quote ID: " & strWhere
    DoCmd.OpenReport "QuotesReport", acViewPreview, , strWhere
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\A\Desktop\Safe\Development\Qutoes\Test Quotes\" & strFileName & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "QuotesReport"
End If
```

This code runs on the Formatting of the report. I have four similar checks. I wonder if this is not efficient and contributes to crashing??

```
'See if the optional section has items, if not set height to 0
Dim optionalSQL As String
Dim optionalDB As DAO.Database
Dim optionalRS As DAO.Recordset

optionalSQL = "SELECT Top 1 OptionalItems.ID FROM OptionalItems LEFT JOIN     Quotes On OptionalItems.quoteID = Quotes.ID WHERE Quotes.QuoteNumber = " & "'" &      Me.[reportQuoteNumber] & "'"


Set optionalDB = CurrentDb
Set optionalRS = optionalDB.OpenRecordset(optionalSQL)

Debug.Print "Optional record count: " & optionalRS.RecordCount

If optionalRS.RecordCount = 0 Then

    Me!OptionalItems_subreport.Height = 0

Else

End If

optionalRS.Close
Set optionalRS = Nothing
Set optionalDB = Nothing
```

Comment: It happens pretty quick, so I can read the entire box, however, a box pops up and says "Now outputting..." in the middle it starts to list what looks like a file name. Then almost immediately the "Microsoft Office Access has stopped working box" pops up and Access shuts down.

Comment: I do have some code in Detail_Format that runs when I open the Print Preview. I'll add that code to the question above.

Comment: When I use the debugger on the formatting code, I notice that this check for records runs twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop:

```
strFileName = Me.[QuoteNumber]
If Len(Dir("C:\Users\A\Desktop\Safe\Development\Qutoes\Test Quotes\" & strFileName & ".pdf")) = 0 Then
    Response = vbYes
Else
    Response = MsgBox("That file already exists! Should I continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists!")
End If

If Response = vbYes Then
    strWhere = "[ID] = " & Me.[ID]
    Debug.Print "Quote ID: " & strWhere
    DoCmd.OpenReport "QuotesReport", acViewPreview, , strWhere
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\A\Desktop\Safe\Development\Qutoes\Test Quotes\" & strFileName & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "QuotesReport"
End If
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I don't think I explained well. I don't want a loop, however, this code keeps crashing Access. I was wondering if I inadvertently created a loop.

Comment: I think your suggestion may miss a part of my objective with this code. I am trying to accommodate three contingencies: 1)if the file does not exist I would like to immediately save my PDF. 2)If the file already exists and I choose "No" to overwriting, I would like to exit the sub. 3)If the fie already exists and I choose "Yes" to overwriting, I would like to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: You should be able to figure that out. However, see edit.